# ORM without database foreign key

Tags: c#, database, orm, sql-server-2012, asp.net-web-api2

I have an old database, where tables have no primary-foreign key relation. And I can't change/add relations in the database now.

I'm trying to use `Entity Framework` or an `ORM tool`. Please tell me if it is possible to use any ORM in this kind of situation? If not, what will be appropriate way to design my DAL?

I'm using `ASP.NET Web API`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Dapper.NET

- [Official Github page here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)
- [Intro CodeProject article here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212274/A-Look-at-Dapper-NET)

Since it just basically "hydrates" whatever an arbitrary SQL statement returns, it'll be able to handle even such a crappy database design - as long as you can express your query in T-SQL, Dapper can build you some nice .NET objects for it.

Dapper is also the lightweight ORM used by Stackoverflow itself :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your database tables have primary keys, you will be able to use Entity Framework for the basics like mapping your table rows to C# objects and doing LINQ-to-Entity queries.

However without foreign keys, you won't be able to take advantage of [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj713564.aspx). This will mean that a number of things will be more manual and long-winded than if you had proper foreign keys but you should still be able to do any data manipulation that you want.

Comment: If you can help me anyway how I can call my Stored Procedures in SQL Server via Entity Framework. I tried it, but either gives an error, or does not return anything.